# Is there a reason why Zoom didn't just kill Barry outright?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In "The Flash" Season 2 Episode 6, Zoom hits Barry 700 times and then parades him around Central City. When Zoom killed everyone at Jitters, he simply broke their necks. Why would Zoom waste time and energy pulverizing Barry when he could have just broken his neck?

Comment: I've not seen the show but surely you've answered this yourself: _"Zoom hits Barry 700 times and then **parades him around Central City.**"_ Seems like Zoom was showing everyone who's boss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are only now watching the show, this might be a spoiler. But it explains why he doesn't kill him.

> Zoom's motivation is not to kill Barry, but to steal his Speed Force in order to add it to his own. He is addicted to getting more and more Speed Force.

[image: Zoom holds Flash by the throat]

Comment: Shouldn't he be able to take over the amount of speed force Flash is tapping into if he simply killed Flash though? Although my only knowledge about that comes from an animated movie, so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Clockwork I can't remember exactly, but I think Barry has to willingly give it up to him. Basically he had to subjugate Barry to the point where he is willing to surrender.

Answer (score 2):

Note: this is more a comment on Jack B Nimble's answer, but I write it as an answer due to spoilers.

As said in the other answer, not only

> Zoom wants to steal the speed of spedsters from other universes, to be the fastest spedsters of the multi-verse

but he also needs Barry and team Flash to

> restore his body damaged by a problematic early version of the Velocity serum.

In the show, Jay Garrick

> is actually Zoom infiltrating team Flash to get the team's help to create the Velocity serum. He is losing his powers (life too?) and is finally saved by the Velocity 9 created by Caitlin.